# Missing special character in web api controller - c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm working with special character and I'm sending request to my .net core web api, request-payload looks like this:

```
{sortBy: "title", isSortAscending: false, page: 1, pageSize: 5, quickSearch: "Magič"}
```

as you can see I wrote "Magič" instead of "Magic" but when I hit my `api/GetProducts` endpoint, I receive this prop like this:

[image]

What do I need to do to recieve special character just as I send it to server ?

I've tried adding configuration related to culture info to startup.cs:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("bs-Latn-BA");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "BAM";

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

But unfortunatelly this did not work.

I've tried also since I know Bosnian culture support this "č", "ć" etc.

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("bs");
```

But this neither work..

Obviously I'm doing something wrong :(

Comment: The JSON default charset is UTF-8. It could be that the server/client sends you invalid JSON (incorrectly coded as Latin-1 which will probably make it look like bad UTF-8 to the parser)

Answer (score 0):

You can **encode** input from Frontend code and **decode** in C#.

For example, I can use `encodeURIComponent('Magič')` in frontend and it returns string **"Magi%C4%8D"**

Then I use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(pagingRequest.QuickSearch)` in C# to get string **"Magič"**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADn2g.png)

Comment: Makes sense if `quickSearch` is passed in the URI and not the body. (lose the image link though.)

Comment: It is not problem. You can encode before concatenate query string in frontend code and decode in C# also. 
I just give an example with `encodeURIComponent()`, you can use other encode algorithms

Comment: When I code example like @Roxy'Pro, I do not catch this error in neither query string nor body.
So I supposed that he wanted to pass parameters FromBody. 
I agree with you that using FromQuery is a better approach when we build RESTFul APIs